# Having issue when getting JWT token by using Docusign API

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am new to DocuSign API and was following this link https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt to get a JWT token. Unfortunately I couldnt get the token correctly. I followed step by step but get 400 in the response.

Tried the example on its Github repo by using a sandbox, but got 400 in the response. If I don't use the user id, only the client Id in the call, I was able to get the token but empty in its payload. Does anyone have the same or similar issue? Any help appreciated.

```
  public @ResponseBody String getToken() throws IOException, ApiException {
    log.info("oauth url: " + baseUrl);
    log.info("clientId: " + clientId);
    log.info("userId: " + userId);
    log.info("secret: " + secret);

    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(baseUrl, "docusignAccessCode", clientId, secret);
    List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList(OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE);
    privateKey = privateKey.replace("\\n", "\n");

    log.info(privateKey);

    OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(clientId, userId, scopes, privateKey.getBytes(), 3600);
    // tried this as well but got empty payload in the token
    // apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(clientId, scopes, privateKey.getBytes(), 3600);

    return oAuthToken.getAccessToken();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this issue, and managed to resolve it : 
Actually its just a bug in the DocuSign API that should return the message "consent_required", but It doesn't.

So you can check in the code where you have the line to manage this error (JWTExample.java:78), and do what it says (it builds a URL for you that you should access with your browser and the impersonated user logged in, to give consent to this user)

After that it should work